# How to use LINQ to take x rows from a multi column list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that looks something like this:

```
catId    itemId    value
  1        5         "some text"
  1        19        "some text"
  1        21        "some text"
  2        6         "some text"
  2        8         "some text"
  3        9         "some text"
  3        82        "some text"
```

Notice the `catId` column. How would I take 2 rows(or remove extra rows) for each unique value in the first colum. Only 2 rows for `catId=1` 2 rows for `catId=2` and so on?

My list is called `distinctXSelling` and I'm using it like this currently:

```
            foreach (var item in distinctXSelling)
            {
                xSelling.InnerHtml += item.value;
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can group items by their category-id and then pick the first two items from each group, before flattening the sequence of groups into a sequence of source-items. This would look like:

```
var query = source.GroupBy(item => item.catId)
                  .SelectMany(catGroup => catGroup.Take(2));
```

Note that the [`Take`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062.aspx) method takes *upto* a certain number of items, so this won't throw if a category has only a single item.

As BrokenGlass points out, you might need a `.OrderBy` (and possibly a `.ThenBy`) if you want the filtered items out in a specific order.

You might also want to consider replacing the loop with:

```
xSelling.InnerHtml = string.Concat(query.Select(item => item.value));
```

Comment: might want to add an `g.OrderBy( x=> x.itemId)` otherwise the order is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to filter the set to a specific column, use `Where()`

```
var onlyCatOne = mySet.Where(x => x.catId == 1)
```

If you want to group by all of them, use `Group()`

```
var groups = mySet.GroupBy(x => x.catId)

foreach(var group in groups)
{
   // Do Stuff
}
```